# What data does the SCOM agent look at in an MS SQL environment?

Tags: scom

I'm a new (US based) SCOM admin and have been asked to add a few of our SQL servers located in the UK to our monitoring.  The question coming from the UK admins is "Is there a possibility that a SCOM component (agent) will look at any sovereign data?"

I'm pretty sure that the answer is 'no', but would like to hear from an experienced SCOM admin as to the data that SCOM **would** look at in an MS SQL environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no," the SQL management pack for SCOM will not look at any sovereign data.

For the most part, the SQL management pack will only look at WMI information.

More information can be found in the Microsoft supplied documentation that can be found at this location:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56203

If you are interested in learning more about SCOM, please be sure to check out these other two SCOM communities:

Microsoft Operations Manager Forums:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/home?category=systemcenteroperationsmanager

SquaredUp Community Answers:
https://community.squaredup.com/answers/

Thanks